# Determining real $a$ for which $\int_{-1}^\infty\frac{1}{(a-x)^2}\,dx$ converges

Tags: calculus, limits

Can someone please help me?

> Consider the integral
> $$\int_{-1}^\infty\frac{1}{(a-x)^2}\,dx$$
> where $a$ is a real constant. Carefully justify for which values of $a$ the integral converges, and calculate its value for those cases.

I used limit as $t$ goes to infinity and found that the limit is $1/(a+1)$, but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: For which values of $a$ is $1/(a+1)$ finite ?

Comment: Hint: if $a\ge-1$, split the integral into $\int_{-1}^a$ and $\int_a^\infty$, and check whether both parts are finite.

Comment: They are not. How does this help us?

Comment: It helps us since it says that for $a\ge -1$ the function $1/(a-x)^2$ is not integrable on $[-1,\infty)$. Then we cannot even apply the fundamental theorem of calculus and say that $\int_{-1}^t1/(a-x)^2dx=1/(t-a) + 1/(1+a)$. (My comment above was misleading).

Answer (score 1):

To change the limits of the integral from $-1$ to $\infty$ to $0$ to $\infty$, we used the substitution $u = a-x$. This substitution allows us to rewrite the integral in terms of the new variable $u$.

The substitution $u = a-x$ has the effect of shifting the limits of integration. The lower limit of the integral becomes $u = a-(-1) = a+1$, and the upper limit becomes $u = a-\infty = -\infty$.

To find the new limits of integration, we can substitute these values back into the original integral:

$$\int_{-1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(a-x)^2} dx = \int_{a+1}^{-\infty} \frac{1}{u^2} du$$

We can then apply the standard rules for changing the limits of integration to find the new limits:

$$\int_{a+1}^{-\infty} \frac{1}{u^2} du = \int_{-\infty}^{a+1} \frac{1}{(-u)^2} (-du) = \int_{a+1}^{-\infty} \frac{1}{u^2} \, du
 $$

now since $\frac{1}{(-u)^2}$    isn't defined in $0$, when $$0 \geq a+1$$ we get infinity , since $$\begin{cases}
1/u = \infty & \text{when } u = 0 \
\end{cases}$$
so for every $a+1 > 0$ the integral converges and equal to $$\frac{1}{a+1}.$$

Comment: It is simpler to write $$
\int_{ - 1}^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{(a - x)^2 }}\mathrm{d}x}  = \int_{ - 1}^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{(x - a)^2 }}\mathrm{d}x}  = \int_{ - a - 1}^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{u^2 }}\mathrm{d}u} .
$$ Your statement that $u$ is not defined at $0$ is nonsense. It is $u^{-2}$ that is undefined for $u=0$. Why do you use *cases* environment towards the end if you only have one case (i.e., $u=0$)?

Comment: correct my bad I will edit it now